# Touch pad controls

Tags: touchpad, laptop, microsoft-windows

Just installed Elementary on my laptop, switching from Win 10, and I was wondering if there was a way to enable touchpad controls such as swiping up to open multi-task view, swiping side to side to switch between applications?

Comment: Maybe search around for gesture support. There have been a few questions.

Comment: Look [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/14559/touchpad-keyboard-and-other-problems-kernel-4-13),this might help in your case perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to my 2 elementary OS laptops. Give it a try.
https://neal.codes/blog/adding-mac-like-touch-gestures-to-elementary-os

Comment: Hi Eleonor, welcome to the community :) It is recommended in StackExchange Q&A sites to summarize the relevant contents of links in answers (it's ok to copy-paste directly, as a quote, as long as attribution is provided). Otherwise the answers force people to an extra click, and there's the risk that the links go down sometime in the future. Please expand your answer to include the relevant details.

Comment: Oh okay. I understand. Thanks for the reminder @waldyrious