# Touchpad & keyboard (and other) problems kernel 4.13

Tags: updates, keyboard, touchpad, kernel, gesture

When installing loki 0.4.1 (fresh install) everything worked fine,but after updating my laptop my touchpad (synaptics) does not respond to touch input anymore and also when holding down any key it does not hold/repeat anymore. Been searching for an answer or fix but it seems te be related to kernel version 4.13. In my situation best thing to do updating towards a later kernel fixes the problem for me.

Many users have complained about this but there is a short list which might be helpfull in your situation. But you have to figure that out for yourself. Below is the link from another topic (many thx for the one created it) which give you details and some fixes to get you started. Hope this will help in your case too...

https://askubuntu.com/a/995948

Answer (score 0):

Update to kernel 4.15. that solved the problem for me.

PS: I have a laptop with amd a9 cpu.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with my touchpad not working in Manjaro, I went into BIOS and changed the touchpad from Advanced to Basic and the touchpad worked.
Don't know if this will help you.